# Stuck in an infinite constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype chain

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I'm reading through Stoyan Stefanov's Object oriented javascript book and have gotten completely confused. Say I have a function:

```
function Test(){
  this.greeting = 'hello';
}

Test.prototype.farewell = "bye"

test = new Test();

test.constructor; //returns Test()

test.constructor.prototype; //returns {farewell:"bye"}

test.constructor.prototype.constructor; //returns Test()
```

The book says since the prototype is an object, it must have a constructor. But as the above example shows, the prototype's constructor is the same as `test`'s constructor. ie `Test()`

Is this expected?

The book goes on "this might go on a while, but you eventually end up with the built in `Object()` object, which is the highest level parent". However, I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop because all my constructors in the chain return `Test()`, so how can I ever get to `Object()`.

Can anyone help to clear things up? (I'm not even sure why these chains are useful.)

Comment: That's not the chain your book talks about. You're just trapped in the circular reference between a constructor and its `.prototype`

Comment: What is the chain the book is talking about?

Comment: I would think it's talking about the "prototype chain", i.e. the invisible links each object has to the other object from which it inherits properties. E.g. `test -> Test.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null` (where `->` is that link)

Comment: However, the statement "*since the prototype is an object, it must have a constructor*" is rather wrong. Most native objects, and those that e.g. are expressed with object literal, are not really created by a constructor function. If they do have a `.constructor` property, it's only because they inherit it from some object in their prototype chain. And so, yes, that "*the prototype's constructor is the same as test's constructor*" is expected, the prototype's `.constructor` property is set to `Test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right. The prototype object has got the wrong constructor because it's right for the thing that uses it as a prototype but not for itself. That means prototypes are not regular objects in that respect. They have a special role like a class object.

If you didn't notice already, your farewell is like a static member of a classical class. It's not a variable that exists per object.

If the book said you can follow constructor pointers up the chain then it's wrong. You can follow getPrototypeOf() up the chain. {Edited out erroneous under-under-proto stuff here.}

As for why any of this is useful when you have the awesome freedom of duck-typing, well I can't answer that.

Comment: That was supposed to be underscore underscore proto underscore underscore, but the markdown mangled it into boldface.

Comment: You can use `\`__proto__\`` for formatting, but you really just should've used `Object.getPrototypeOf()` instead of `__proto__`

Comment: Good point, and thanks for the formatting tip.